# Tables in same DB shows different value for current_timestamp. How to fix this?

Tags: mysql, laravel, timestamp

I am working on a Laraval app and trying to insert records into two different tables in same DB. I have a field "created_at" in both tables and set to store current_timestamp(to store the timestamp when the record was inserted). But the tables shows different values for these columns.
For example, created_at field in Table-A shows `2023-10-10 11:30:00` and Table-B shows `2023-10-10 02:00:00`.

I want both table to store 2023-10-10 11:30:00.
I tried inserting a new record through phpmyadmin to Table-A and it was showing 2023-10-10 02:00:00 (timestamp as in Table-B).

We have added "Asia/Calcutta" as the timezone in config/app.php

Could some one please tell me the possible reason for this issue or where should I check for a reason?

I was expecting the that both tables store same value(2023-10-10 11:30:00) for the field created_at.

Comment: This question would need more information about the code. Could you share the migrations for both tables and also how you are inserting the data?